# "There is another file or directory with this name. " error while installing inside Windows

Tags: wubi

I tried to install Ubuntu 11.10 inside Windows, it showed error occurred, permission denied, for more see the log file.

Last week I tried to install Xubuntu, it showed same problem. But I installed Ubuntu before trying Xubuntu, it perfectly installed and worked fine. I uninstalled Ubuntu before installing Xubuntu.

I don't understand the log file. It looks like this:

```
04-27 12:24 ERROR  root: Cannot install into D:\ubuntu.
There is another file or directory with this name.
Please remove it before continuing.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 130, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 205, in run_cd_menu
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 120, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 82, in select_target_dir
Exception: Cannot install into D:\ubuntu.
There is another file or directory with this name.
Please remove it before continuing.
04-27 12:25 INFO   root: === wubi 11.10 rev241 ===
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  root: Logfile is c:\users\sialnuan\appdata\local\temp\wubi-11.10-rev241.log
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  root: sys.argv = ['main.pyo', '--exefile="E:\\wubi.exe"', '--cdmenu']
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend: data_dir=C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp\data
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: 7z=C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp\bin\7z.exe
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: startup_folder=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Fetching basic info...
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend: original_exe=E:\wubi.exe
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend: platform=win32
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend: osname=nt
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend: language=en_IN
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend: encoding=cp1252
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: arch=amd64
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Parsing isolist=C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp\data\isolist.ini
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Xubuntu-i386
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Xubuntu-amd64
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-amd64
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-i386
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-amd64
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-i386
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-amd64
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-i386
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Fetching host info...
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: registry_key=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows version=vista
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_version2=Windows 7 Home Premium
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_sp=None
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_build=7600
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: gmt=5
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: country=IN
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: timezone=Asia/Calcutta
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_username=SIALNUAN
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_full_name=SIALNUAN
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_directory=C:\Users\SIALNUAN
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language_code=1033
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language=English
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: processor_name=Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T6600  @ 2.20GHz
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: bootloader=vista
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: system_drive=Drive(C: hd 17858.78125 mb free ntfs)
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(C: hd 17858.78125 mb free ntfs)
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(D: hd 9921.94140625 mb free ntfs)
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(E: cd 0.0 mb free cdfs)
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(F: cd 0.0 mb free cdfs)
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(G: removable 1909.5625 mb free fat)
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(I: hd 169383.378906 mb free ntfs)
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: uninstaller_path=None
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_target_dir=None
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_distro_name=None
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_id=67699721
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_layout=us
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_variant=
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend: python locale=('en_IN', 'cp1252')
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend: locale=en_IN
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: total_memory_mb=2047.99999905
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching ISOs on USB devices
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local CDs
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp is a valid Xubuntu CD
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp is a valid Xubuntu CD
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Xubuntu CD
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Xubuntu CD
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:   parsing info from str=Ubuntu 11.10 "Oneiric Ocelot" - Release i386 (20111012)
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  Distro:   parsed info={'name': 'Ubuntu', 'subversion': 'Release', 'version': '11.10', 'build': '20111012', 'codename': 'Oneiric Ocelot', 'arch': 'i386'}
04-27 12:25 INFO   Distro: Found a valid CD for Ubuntu: E:\
04-27 12:25 INFO   root: Running the CD menu...
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: __init__...
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: on_init...
04-27 12:25 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp\translations, languages=['en_IN', 'en']
04-27 12:25 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp\translations, languages=['en_IN', 'en']
04-27 12:25 INFO   root: CD menu finished
04-27 12:25 INFO   root: Running the installer...
04-27 12:25 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp\translations, languages=['en_IN', 'en']
04-27 12:25 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp\translations, languages=['en_IN', 'en']
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WinuiInstallationPage: target_drive=D:, installation_size=7000MB, distro_name=Ubuntu, language=en_US, locale=en_US.UTF-8, username=sialnuan
04-27 12:25 INFO   root: Received settings
04-27 12:25 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  TaskList: # Running tasklist...
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running select_target_dir...
04-27 12:25 INFO   WindowsBackend: Installing into D:\ubuntu
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished select_target_dir
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running create_dir_structure...
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir D:\ubuntu
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir D:\ubuntu\disks
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir D:\ubuntu\install
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir D:\ubuntu\install\boot
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir D:\ubuntu\disks\boot
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir D:\ubuntu\disks\boot\grub
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir D:\ubuntu\install\boot\grub
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished create_dir_structure
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running uncompress_target_dir...
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished uncompress_target_dir
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running create_uninstaller...
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying uninstaller E:\wubi.exe -> D:\ubuntu\uninstall-wubi.exe
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi UninstallString D:\ubuntu\uninstall-wubi.exe
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi InstallationDir D:\ubuntu
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi DisplayName Ubuntu
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi DisplayIcon D:\ubuntu\Ubuntu.ico
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi DisplayVersion 11.10-rev241
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi Publisher Ubuntu
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi URLInfoAbout http://www.ubuntu.com
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi HelpLink http://www.ubuntu.com/support
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished create_uninstaller
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running copy_installation_files...
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp\data\custom-installation -> D:\ubuntu\install\custom-installation
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp\winboot -> D:\ubuntu\winboot
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\Users\SIALNUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8B7D.tmp\data\images\Ubuntu.ico -> D:\ubuntu\Ubuntu.ico
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished copy_installation_files
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running get_iso...
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  TaskList: New task copy_file
04-27 12:25 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running copy_file...
04-27 12:26 ERROR  TaskList: [Errno 13] Permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\utils.py", line 202, in copy_file
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
04-27 12:26 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
04-27 12:26 ERROR  root: [Errno 13] Permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 130, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 205, in run_cd_menu
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 120, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\utils.py", line 202, in copy_file
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
04-27 12:26 DEBUG  TaskList: New task check_iso
04-27 12:26 ERROR  TaskList: 'WindowsBackend' object has no attribute 'iso_path'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 579, in get_iso
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 565, in use_iso
AttributeError: 'WindowsBackend' object has no attribute 'iso_path'
04-27 12:26 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
04-27 12:26 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
```

Answer (score 2):

> ERROR root: Cannot install into D:\ubuntu. There is another file or
>   directory with this name. Please remove it before continuing.

Either rename or delete the existing file.

Then run Wubi again.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the given data in the given path `C:\..\AppData\Local\Temp`...

My problem was that I named the Folder Ubuntu (in which I kept wubi so it was giving error. The moment I changed the name of the folder to OS it started working... )